# Apps with Action Bar pre-Android 3.0

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I use this in an app that I target Android 3.0+ only.  I'd like to get more people but the ActionBar is not backwards compatible.  I do not want to use a third party library like ActionBarSherlock.  I went down that road and it was more of a pain then it was worth.

I have code like this:

```
final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

It is possible to wrap this with an `if` - `else` SDK check?  Outside of the Action Bar, 99% other code is compatible pre-3.0  (well, I am using Fragments but using the Support Library.)

Comment: ActionBarSherlock is worth the pain

Comment: Actually the question here is: What pain? You just clone it from Github and everything should work smooth. :)

Comment: I have used it and once you can configure everything, it is beautiful, it definitely simplifies life. @Ahmad the jar is a pain to configure. Well it could be just Eclipse...

Comment: Well the tutorial I followed, it seemed like it was importing a whole 'nother app just to use it.  Maybe there is a better way out there, I don't know?  And yes, I use Eclipse.

Comment: Oh my, I just used ActionBarSherlock.  Not NEARLY as bad I remembered in my first attempt.  I think we found a winner!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, something like this:

```
      @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
        private void setupActionBar() {
              if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                 actionBar = getActionBar();
                 actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
                 actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); 
                }           
        }
```

Make sure to have your actionBar variable **global**

Comment: Aghhh, beat me to it by seconds. +1.

Comment: I was having server issues, same for you?

Comment: One more question, is this generally an accepted means or is this a bad hack?

Comment: Accepted, I have used this method ever since I saw it from the ADT's SettingsActivity template. If the Template uses it, I'd assume it's the safe way.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like that:

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I use them quite extensively. However do watch [this](https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/gooio2012/106/) from Google I/O 2012 as it gives good insight into even better practices.

You can get the version as an int using Build.VERSION.SDK_INT. It's easy to set this up:

```
final int version = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
ActionBar actionBar;

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    private void ABsetup() {
        if (version >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);          }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Another option is to use ActionBarSherlock which makes the actionbar back compatible to android 2.1 (SDK 7).

Link here: http://actionbarsherlock.com/

Comment: `I do not want to use a third party library like ActionBarSherlock`